# Magento 1.9.3: Add to cart 404 after moving to new server

Tags: addtocart, server-setup, 404, magento1.9.3

After moving to a new server with plesk, I get a 404 not found when i press add to cart. I am not sure why. I truncated the core_url_rewrite table, deleted everything in var/cache and var/session before moving the site.

An example of the 404 url:

> /checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9lbGVrdHJvbmlrZGVsZS5kay8,/product/1193/form_key/0X2MdMHKzLuVombB/

Magento 1.9.3

Comment: you have the check the permission ?

Comment: I have set all folder permissions to 770 and all file permissions to 660

Answer (score 0):

If the domain is changed, have you check that you updated base urls at `core_config_data` table.

```
web/secure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_url
```

These two values must be your new domain.

Comment: The domain is the same. I suspect that there is some nginx configs that are different. The way the urls are rewritten or something, but I am not sure